# Get correct index with Splice()

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, angularjs, splice

I'm attempting to delete items from my AngularJS view. From the view, I'm passing the index & the ID. In the JS controller, I *splice(index)* from the AngularJS array/model. And I pass the ID to a *$http.get* to call a delete to my database. This all works.

....

Until I make a request to refresh my page. Every 5 seconds I make a request to update the Angular model and I concat any new data to it. But what I'm finding is it screws up my index values. I assumed it was reordering my index: and reading [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461133/why-does-the-splice-method-have-this-strange-behavior) helped confirm that.

What would happen is that I push delete for the 3rd item on the page, and it deletes that ID from the DB. But it splices the wrong item from the page until I refresh the page.
**How do I make sure that I'm always passing the correct index?**

***View***

```
<li ng-repeat="new in news | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
     <div class="newsitem" id="newspost{{new.id}}">
         <h4 ng-model="news.title">{{new.title}} </h4>
         <p ng-model="news.text">{{new.text}}</p>
         <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="visible = true">View article</a>
         <a ng-click="deleteNews(index,new.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a>
     </div>
</li>
```

***controllers.js***

```
$scope.deleteNews = function(index, id) {
    $http.get('/ci/index.php/news/delete_news_ajax/'+id).success(function(){
        $scope.news.splice(index, 1);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the index and id, pass `new`:

```
<a ng-click="deleteNews(new)" ...>
```

Then use `indexOf` in your controller function:

```
$scope.deleteNews = function(newsItem) {
   $http.get('/ci/index.php/news/delete_news_ajax/' + newsItem.id)).success(function() {
      $scope.news.splice($scope.news.indexOf(newsItem), 1);
   });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I think that is because `new` is a reserved word in JavaScript.  Use `newsItem`.

Comment: That works wonderfully well. It almost seems to be too easy. AND it solved another issue that I was having when ordering things (But I wasn't too concerned about that.)